# Talkback is announcing the app name on tap of element in certain timeout but it is not consistent - React Native

Tags: react-native, talkback

Talkback is announcing the app name on tap of element in certain timeout but it is not consistent - React Native

I tried to find out that the app name where it is announcing by talk back but didn't get the solution. Why it is announcing or to stop the announcement of app name.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.